# Overwrite BlazeDS / FlexDataservice endpoint

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, blazeds

I'm using the build in Flex Dataservice to connect to a BlazeDS server. 
Flex is using the *.fml file within the model folder for the connection details, within that file you can find the following:

```
<annotation name="ServiceConfig">
  <item name="DEFAULT_ENTITY_PACKAGE">valueObjects</item>
  <item name="contextRoot">/MYWEBAPP</item>
  <item name="rootUrl">http://192.168.178.21:8080/MYWEBAPP</item>
  <item name="LINKED_FILE"></item>
  <item name="ABSOLUTE_ENDPOINT">http://192.168.178.21:8080/MYWEBAPP/messagebroker/amf</item>
</annotation>
```

the _super_Database class created by Flex DataService uses that configuration to setup a remote object for communications.
Now i'm looking for a way to overwrite those settings within the Database class which extends the _super_Database class. can anyone assist?

Comment: I don't know what "the *.fml" file is; nor do I know what the Database class you're referring to is.  Which type of remote service call are you using?  ( AMF with RemoteObjoct or are you using 'remote object' as a generic term for a remote server call? )

Comment: AMF with RemoteObject. But I'm using Flash-Builder DataService, which generates all needed mirror classes and creates a service class. also it creates a *.fml file which basicly contains metadata for flash-builder. when setting up a server for the flex project, all the server data is stored within the fml file too. and flashbuilder dataservice is using this data for the remoteobject setup - but i want to overwrite that with data i load from a custom properties file.

Comment: that server data is also located within the .flexProperties file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define channels and other RemoteObject information at run-time without specifying a services-config file at compile time; then you can use this [link](http://www.mikenimer.com/?p=320) to give you the information you need to do that.

Comment: thats what i was looking for, thanks! Raghu is also talking about it here: [link](http://raghuonflex.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/endpointatruntime/) - just in case anyone ever needs it: the internal Flex DataService / Remote Object Access Service endpoints / destination and so on is setup within [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/com/adobe/fiber/services/wrapper/RemoteObjectServiceWrapper.html) class. using overwrite. atm i just cant get it working the way it should (bug?)

Comment: also take care about [this little bastard](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/541674#541674). it will cause a Error #2048 because its trying to redict using http://localhost:37813. If you want to overrride the default Remote Object Access Service service like mentioned in the blog posts above, the thing you should care about are the _serviceControl.channelSet and _serviceControl.destination properties which you should override in your service class (which is inheriting from the _super_service class created by flex)